# @Singleton @Startup fully Asynchronous?

Tags: java, asynchronous, singleton, startup

I am using the @Singleton and @Startup annotations together to create a long running process. By using these annotation can I safely assume that my process will be a single thread running fully asynchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these annotations just at the class-level, so I'm not sure what 'process' do you refer to (@PostConstruct method?)

I don't remember any part of the EJB 3.1 specification which talks about the required asynchronous singleton initialization.

**4.8.1 Singleton Initialization:**

> (...)the bean developer can optionally configure the Singleton
>   for eager initialization. If the Startup annotation appears on the
>   Singleton bean class (...) the container must initialize the Singleton bean instance **during the application startup sequence**. The container must initialize all such
>   startup-time Singletons **before any client requests are delivered to
>   any enterprise bean components in the application.**

It rather depends on the Application Server vendor what technique of initialization he choose. **I would not assume that the loading will occur in a separate process** but rather just that it will occur during server startup and before serving clients.

ENTERED FROM COMMENTS:
what about providing a separate asynchronous EJB method for your time-consuming operation which will be invoked from your singleton initializer EJB?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I'm using JBOSS and yes when I say 'process' I do mean the @PostConstruct annotated method :P Every time I try to deploy it I try to hit my RESTeasy API and the request just seem to hang :( It seems as thought the startup 'process' is behaving synchronously and because my 'process' executed in an infinite loop that nothing else can get through... Does that sound realistic?

Comment: @travega - just shooting here - what about providing a separate asynchronous EJB method for your time-consuming operation which will be invoked from your singleton initializer EJB?

Comment: Hmm yes I could definitely give that a try... Certainly the singleton process seems to be blocking any other functionality in my program from working. I'll give it a shot. Thanks