# Spring: Singleton that should be loaded initialized at startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, singleton, startup

I have a Spring (Boot) application that does some heavy NLP text processing. I'm looking for a way to optimize performance by loading some models upfront and only once.

### Scenario

There is a `@Service` that consists of several methods to analyse a text (e.g. extract keywords). Pre-trained models will be loaded by the NLP framework I use in my service, which takes a lot of time and memory. The models can be re-used so there is no need to load them every time. The most efficient way would be to load them once and keep them in memory. You can also assume that the models are Thread-safe.

### Question

What is the best way to define a singleton and initialize it once at startup?

For now I use `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)` on my service but there is no guarantee that the service will be initialized at startup as far as I understood. I also experimented with `@Configuration` but didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

[FactoryBeans](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) can support singletons and prototypes, and can either create objects lazily on demand or eagerly on startup.

Answer (score 1):

As far i understand, if you use "@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)" then your service will be initialized at startup. Please see the below post for more information:
[@Singleton @Startup fully Asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841991/singleton-startup-fully-asynchronous?rq=1)

Comment: The post is about Java EE but not Spring. I guess that behavior is not applicable then.

Answer (score 1):

Use @PostConstruct annotation on one of the method of your service and it will be called after the instance has been created.

Comment: I would love to have the explanation about the downvote reason and proposed solution/answer  from  downvote author

Comment: Wasn't my vote but I guess instance creation != application startup

Comment: Well, all singletons are eagerly instantiated during startup unless they are lazy... I just suggested the way for proper initialization...

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Core when you declare class as bean it's default scope is Singleton. When you start the application Spring try initialize the class. If there is dependencies it initialize the dependencies first and then the class. In my opinion you should not use scope.

```
@Service
public class Foo {
}
```

This is enough to create bean which is initialized at the start up.

Sorry if i did not understand something.

Best regards,
Petar.

Comment: Indeed that seems to be the default behavior. But I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation about this so I wasn't sure.

Comment: You can check your tomcat/other logs, with log4j/other with debug mode. It clearly indicates the bean with `@Service` will be created and initialized on startup.